# how to know the sutible PHP version to use with PHP Zend framework version?

Tags: php, zend-framework, localhost, localserver

I have a project that is built with `PHP Zend framework`, but when i ran it i got errors that is probably due to the current php version i am using in `Xamp`, so i need to figure out the suitable php version to install in the local server (`Xamp` or `Wamp`) for the `zend framework`. below are the details:

**Zend framework version: 2.4.0**

**PHP Version 5.4.4**

it seems that this combination has too many errors

Comment: why not check the requirements per Zend version?

Comment: Regardless of the actual requirements, you should really be using something more recent than 5.4.4 anyway.

Comment: @PatrickQ some framework versions require an old php versions! and i think that the project i am working on is old

Comment: @AliAlAmine  If a framework version requires a PHP version that old, then _you should not be using that framework version_.  That being said, I can pretty much guarantee that you do _not_ need a version older than 5.4 to run ZF2, because I was running ZF1 on PHP 7.

Comment: @PatrickQ well it's my first time working with Zend framework, and i had faced such versions problems with other PHP frameworks. Thank you anw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have to search for the framework on Github, switch to that specific release tag and open `composer.json` file. In there you could find the required PHP version.

This is the link to zend 2.4.0 composer.json file: https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/blob/release-2.4.0/composer.json

It says `"php": ">=5.3.23"`